# Enlarge the image from camera roll and use edited image

Tags: swift

I'm making a mobile app in XCode using Swift. In my application I'm selecting an image from my phone's camera roll and running that image through Googles Vision API. Currently, if I select an image, it passes in the whole image to the analyzer. What I'd like to have is that the user selects an image from their camera roll and zooms into a specific item in that image, and when they press 'Choose', we pass that zoomed part of the image into the analyzer instead of the whole image.

This is my code so far:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = pickedImage
        spinner.startAnimating()


        // Base64 encode the image and create the request
        let binaryImageData = base64EncodeImage(pickedImage)
        createRequest(with: binaryImageData)
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm sure there's some code I can put in this section to allow the user to use the edited image.
Anyone have a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` which passes the default image, you need to replace it with `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` if you wish to use the manipulated image, i.e. the "zoomed image".

So this is how it would look for your specific project:

```
if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage** instead of **UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    print(info)
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        print(pickedImage)
        print(pickedImage.size)
    }


}
```